# Override SQL Alchemy ORM filter condition

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, where-clause

How can I undo a filter condition on an SQLAlchemy query? E.g.

```
q = Model.query.filter(Model.age > 25)
q = q.remove_filter(Model.age)  # what is this called?
```

Comment: If there are several filters by age in the query, do you need to remove them all?

Comment: btw why would you need that?

Comment: What I always do is create a list of filters: `filters = []` and then instead of adding the filters to the query one by one, I add them to the list one by one: `if x != y: filters.append(Model.x == y)` and this way you can remove them too if needed. Now finally when you execute the query, just do `q = q.filter(and_(*filters))`

Comment: Although this really sounds like a design issue, what is your use case?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to other suggestions, the simple (but if it's actually simple depends on your exact situation) solution can be to just not apply the filters you don't need.

Most probably you have some complex code that conditionally applies the filters and then you have a case when you want to undo some filters.
In this case, instead of applying all the filters to the query, you could collect the filters you need into some collection, for example a dictionary or a list.

Then you remove filters you don't need from the dictionary and then you actually apply these collected filters to the query object.

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe that feature currently exists. That being said, you can view (and delete) the where clauses (filters) by directly accessing the `q.whereclause.clauses` list of BinaryExpression objects.

If that's your only filter, something like this would work:

`q.whereclause.clauses.pop()`

But it gets a little trickier (and hackier) if you want to remove a specific filter out of many.